# Asignación de turno a jornada de trabajo (Mañana/Tarde/Noche) en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ayuda!!!

Me encuentro realizando una consulta mediante `SQL` a una base de datos que es alimentada por un programa donde personal registra cantidad de defectos a lo largo de su jornada de trabajo, el formato une fecha y hora de acuerdo al registro `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000"`, no tengo ningún problema con la consulta en si, sin embrago me gustaría poder determinar en base a las horas de registro el turno como muestro a continuación:

> De 22:30:00 a 06:00:00 --> Turno 1 o Nocturno
>
> De 06:00:00 a 14:30:00 --> Turno 2 o Matutino
>
> De 14:30:00 a 22:30:00 --> Turno 3 o Vespertino

He tratado de usar `CASE` pero sin éxito, alguien podría darme una recomendación para agregar una columna a mi consulta y que me arroje el turno?

Comment: Hola podrias mostrar lo que has intentado y la definición de tu tabla para poder tratar de ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3):

Para este tipo de casos, yo usualmente me valgo de un pequeño truco, para poder comparar de manera fácil horas y minutos, y es obtener un solo número que mezcle ambas, trataré de explicarme con un ejemplo:

Si tengo la hora `14:17:15`, voy a obtener el número entero con valor `1417` (si, mil cuatrocientos diecisiete), de manera que se simplifique la comparación, por ejemplo, con un rango de horas y minutos, o con otros registros.

Para hacerlo, obtengo la hora y los minutos, y luego hago un *corrimiento* de dos posiciones decimales de la hora.

En TSQL, eso sería algo como:

```
datepart(hour, FechaHora) * 100 + datepart(minute, FechaHora)
```

Para construir la solución final, también voy a valerme de un *CTE* en el que hago este cálculo, en el campo `HHMM`. Finalmente, utilizo este campo para determinar la jornada.

Luego, para cada jornada, a falta de claridad del requerimiento, he definido que se tomará en cuenta todos los registros que son mayor o igual que la hora de inicio y menor que la hora final. (de otra forma un registro a las `14:30` sería a la vez de la jornada matutina y la vespertina).

Otra simplificación que he realizado, dado que la hora de inicio de la jornada nocturna es mayor que la hora final, pero no en las otras dos, la dejo al final en el `else` de la sentencia `case`.

Esta consulta

```
with
Registro as (
select *
  from (values (cast('20190814 11:17:00' as datetime))
             , ('20190814 14:29:00')
             , ('20190814 14:30:00')
             , ('20190814 19:45:00')
             , ('20190814 22:29:00')
             , ('20190814 22:30:00')
             , ('20190814 23:59:00')
             , ('20190815 01:00:00')
             , ('20190815 05:59:59')
             , ('20190815 06:00:00')
       ) a (fechahora)
)
,
Base as (
select   Registro.fechahora
       , datepart(hour, Registro.FechaHora) * 100 + datepart(minute, Registro.FechaHora) HHMM
  from Registro
)
select   Base.FechaHora
       , case 
           when Base.HHMM >= 0600 and Base.HHMM < 1430 then 'Matutino'
           when Base.HHMM >= 1430 and Base.HHMM < 2230 then 'Vespertino'
           else 'Nocturno'
         end Turno
  from Base
```

Produce este resultado:

```
FechaHora               Turno
----------------------- ----------
2019-08-14 11:17:00.000 Matutino
2019-08-14 14:29:00.000 Matutino
2019-08-14 14:30:00.000 Vespertino
2019-08-14 19:45:00.000 Vespertino
2019-08-14 22:29:00.000 Vespertino
2019-08-14 22:30:00.000 Nocturno
2019-08-14 23:59:00.000 Nocturno
2019-08-15 01:00:00.000 Nocturno
2019-08-15 05:59:59.000 Nocturno
2019-08-15 06:00:00.000 Matutino

(10 rows affected)
```

Comment: Buen día @jachguate, esta solución me fui muy de mucha ayuda, lo único que cambie un poco fue el usar el Datepart de horas y minutos dentro del mismo CASE y funciono a la perfección:

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, @JosePalacios, yo me voy por una consulta más legible, por eso suelo _factorizar_ el cálculo en un CTE y luego utilizarlo, pero el resultado (y probablemente el plan de ejecución) es el mismo. Enhorabuena.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma ligeramente distinta a la que ya te dió jachguate es usar los segundos  desde la hora `00:00:00` de cada fechahora, y establecer previamente los límites de cada turno:

```
select  CASE    
        WHEN datediff(ss, cast(fechahora as DATE), fechahora) between 21600 and 52200 - 1 THEN 'Matutino'
        WHEN datediff(ss, cast(fechahora as DATE), fechahora) between 52200 and 81000 - 1 THEN 'Vespertino'
        ELSE 'Nocturno'
    end
    from TuTabla
    order by fechahora;
```

No está de más decirte que tal vez te convenga crear una tabla de turnos que quite la lógica "dura" en el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, ambos códigos el tuyo y de @jachguate me funcionaron de maravilla, tomare en cuenta tu comentario para crear una tabla de turnos.